# How to find the ID of the selected object in the layer? PyQGIS 3.0

Tags: pyqgis, layers, qgis-3

How can I get a list of the ID of these selected objects?

[image]

QGIS 3.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [QgsVectorLayer::selectedFeatureIds()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a62cf5c302ede7692ed049a1f1bcaec3f) to get a list of selected feature ids:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer.selectedFeatureIds())
```